# django how to assign a User foreign key id within view

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a model with a foreign key which references the django model User.
I have found that you are supposed to use this model when creating something like this:

```
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

however any time i try to assign this from my view with this line:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        c = form.save(commit=False)
        c.author=request.user.id
        c.save()
```

I get an error complaining about how author should come from the model User. There is no User property (at least that i (a noob working on their first django project) could find) which has the user id. what is the preferred method for linking a post to it's author in django? am i going about this completely the wrong way? is there a better way of solving this problem that i am just not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just assign this only not id,

```
c.author=request.user
```

Comment: this one worked too. if i could give 2 correct i would for 2 different correct answers. i will give credit to the first unless one performs better. thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

For assigning user, it should be like:

```
c.author= User.objects.filter(id= request.user.id)[0]
```

Comment: this worked awesomely. thank you so much. you saved my brain a lot of trouble.

Comment: -1. This is totally pointless. `request.user` is already the User object, there is absolutely no point in querying for it again. Plus, you should do a `get`, not `filter()[0]` if you only want one object.